# My node-red flow doesn't complete?

Tags: node-red, homekit

The below flow should bridge Garageio to Homekit in a way that should emulate a native garage door opener. This is done using the node-red-contrib-homekit package. But, something isn't right. What should happen when the TargetDoorState is set to 0 from the Homekit node, is a request is sent to Garageio (using the script for modularity) to open the garage, and then the TargetDoorState is kept the same while the CurrentDoorState is grabbed from Garageio every five seconds. Problem is, I don't know where to begin to describe the problem. I've fixed bugs in the nodes such as typos and such, and they've only created more problems. Can anyone take a look at this and point out some flaws that may impact the functionality of this flow?

```
[
    {
        "id":"b958107d.b6335",
        "type":"tab",
        "label":"Flow 4",
        "disabled":false,
        "info":""
    },
    {
        "id":"df37ea51.7e2408",
        "type":"inject",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"Every 15 Minutes",
        "topic":"",
        "payload":"",
        "payloadType":"str",
        "repeat":"900",
        "crontab":"",
        "once":false,
        "onceDelay":0.1,
        "x":210,
        "y":400,
        "wires":[
            [
                "31140bd3.427a74"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"7a6ce21f.d570bc",
        "type":"inject",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"Every 5 Seconds",
        "topic":"",
        "payload":"",
        "payloadType":"str",
        "repeat":"5",
        "crontab":"",
        "once":false,
        "onceDelay":0.1,
        "x":210,
        "y":660,
        "wires":[
            [
                "dcd5850b.fef318"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"31140bd3.427a74",
        "type":"exec",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "command":"/home/carter/garage/scripts/renew",
        "addpay":false,
        "append":"",
        "useSpawn":"false",
        "timer":"",
        "oldrc":false,
        "name":"Renew Authentication",
        "x":460,
        "y":400,
        "wires":[
            [

            ],
            [

            ],
            [

            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"dcd5850b.fef318",
        "type":"exec",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "command":"/home/carter/garage/scripts/status",
        "addpay":false,
        "append":"",
        "useSpawn":"false",
        "timer":"",
        "oldrc":false,
        "name":"Get Status",
        "x":430,
        "y":660,
        "wires":[
            [
                "eb7aa22f.20c8d",
                "498df0d3.d4573"
            ],
            [

            ],
            [

            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"9955aba3.f58108",
        "type":"exec",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "command":"/home/carter/garage/scripts/close",
        "addpay":true,
        "append":"",
        "useSpawn":"false",
        "timer":"",
        "oldrc":false,
        "name":"POST Close",
        "x":2090,
        "y":600,
        "wires":[
            [
                "9d1ae463.3415e8"
            ],
            [

            ],
            [

            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"994542c8.d4801",
        "type":"exec",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "command":"/home/carter/garage/scripts/open",
        "addpay":false,
        "append":"",
        "useSpawn":"false",
        "timer":"",
        "oldrc":false,
        "name":"POST Open",
        "x":2090,
        "y":720,
        "wires":[
            [
                "abfaea0c.cf3608"
            ],
            [

            ],
            [

            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"f03f1531.aa66e8",
        "type":"file",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"Write to File",
        "filename":"/home/carter/garage/vars/tds",
        "appendNewline":false,
        "createDir":false,
        "overwriteFile":"true",
        "x":2550,
        "y":720,
        "wires":[

        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"2778e858.697218",
        "type":"file",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"Write to File",
        "filename":"/home/carter/garage/vars/tds",
        "appendNewline":false,
        "createDir":false,
        "overwriteFile":"true",
        "x":2550,
        "y":600,
        "wires":[

        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"253a0e02.550b52",
        "type":"switch",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"",
        "property":"payload.TargetDoorState",
        "propertyType":"msg",
        "rules":[
            {
                "t":"eq",
                "v":"1",
                "vt":"num"
            },
            {
                "t":"eq",
                "v":"0",
                "vt":"num"
            }
        ],
        "checkall":"true",
        "repair":false,
        "outputs":2,
        "x":1850,
        "y":660,
        "wires":[
            [
                "9955aba3.f58108"
            ],
            [
                "994542c8.d4801"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"9d1ae463.3415e8",
        "type":"change",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"",
        "rules":[
            {
                "t":"set",
                "p":"payload",
                "pt":"msg",
                "to":"1",
                "tot":"num"
            }
        ],
        "action":"",
        "property":"",
        "from":"",
        "to":"",
        "reg":false,
        "x":2320,
        "y":600,
        "wires":[
            [
                "2778e858.697218",
                "c83a643c.349788",
                "1c403c26.e50284"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"abfaea0c.cf3608",
        "type":"change",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"",
        "rules":[
            {
                "t":"set",
                "p":"payload",
                "pt":"msg",
                "to":"0",
                "tot":"num"
            }
        ],
        "action":"",
        "property":"",
        "from":"",
        "to":"",
        "reg":false,
        "x":2320,
        "y":720,
        "wires":[
            [
                "f03f1531.aa66e8",
                "b056b7c4.7ac138",
                "3bca3efe.237552"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"3bca3efe.237552",
        "type":"file",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"Flag as Changing State",
        "filename":"/home/carter/garage/vars/changing",
        "appendNewline":false,
        "createDir":false,
        "overwriteFile":"true",
        "x":2590,
        "y":680,
        "wires":[

        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"498df0d3.d4573",
        "type":"file in",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"Check Flag",
        "filename":"/home/carter/garage/vars/changing",
        "format":"utf8",
        "chunk":false,
        "sendError":false,
        "x":650,
        "y":660,
        "wires":[
            [
                "919f30b2.fd435"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"eb7aa22f.20c8d",
        "type":"switch",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"What's the state?",
        "property":"payload",
        "propertyType":"msg",
        "rules":[
            {
                "t":"cont",
                "v":"closed",
                "vt":"str"
            },
            {
                "t":"cont",
                "v":"open",
                "vt":"str"
            }
        ],
        "checkall":"true",
        "repair":false,
        "outputs":2,
        "x":670,
        "y":980,
        "wires":[
            [
                "3097905d.4b7f5"
            ],
            [
                "170d3830.0c2528"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"3097905d.4b7f5",
        "type":"change",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"Closed",
        "rules":[
            {
                "t":"set",
                "p":"payload",
                "pt":"msg",
                "to":"1",
                "tot":"num"
            }
        ],
        "action":"",
        "property":"",
        "from":"",
        "to":"",
        "reg":false,
        "x":920,
        "y":920,
        "wires":[
            [
                "c8f8bf80.72181",
                "f7605409.237dc8"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"170d3830.0c2528",
        "type":"change",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"Open",
        "rules":[
            {
                "t":"set",
                "p":"payload",
                "pt":"msg",
                "to":"0",
                "tot":"num"
            }
        ],
        "action":"",
        "property":"",
        "from":"",
        "to":"",
        "reg":false,
        "x":910,
        "y":1040,
        "wires":[
            [
                "fcf1b6e7.a94ff8",
                "238c6754.5f47d8"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"c8f8bf80.72181",
        "type":"file",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"Write to File",
        "filename":"/home/carter/garage/vars/cds",
        "appendNewline":false,
        "createDir":false,
        "overwriteFile":"true",
        "x":1150,
        "y":920,
        "wires":[

        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"fcf1b6e7.a94ff8",
        "type":"file",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"Write to File",
        "filename":"/home/carter/garage/vars/cds",
        "appendNewline":false,
        "createDir":false,
        "overwriteFile":"true",
        "x":1130,
        "y":1040,
        "wires":[

        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"919f30b2.fd435",
        "type":"switch",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"Is Flag Set?",
        "property":"payload",
        "propertyType":"msg",
        "rules":[
            {
                "t":"eq",
                "v":"1",
                "vt":"num"
            },
            {
                "t":"else"
            }
        ],
        "checkall":"true",
        "repair":false,
        "outputs":2,
        "x":790,
        "y":560,
        "wires":[
            [
                "b97366ab.e6f5c8"
            ],
            [
                "d94542f3.a9a38"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"d94542f3.a9a38",
        "type":"file in",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"No (Get Current State)",
        "filename":"/home/carter/garage/vars/cds",
        "format":"utf8",
        "chunk":false,
        "sendError":false,
        "x":1040,
        "y":660,
        "wires":[
            [
                "b51b8ac4.bf56a8"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"b51b8ac4.bf56a8",
        "type":"switch",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"Whats the state?",
        "property":"payload",
        "propertyType":"msg",
        "rules":[
            {
                "t":"eq",
                "v":"1",
                "vt":"num"
            },
            {
                "t":"eq",
                "v":"0",
                "vt":"num"
            }
        ],
        "checkall":"true",
        "repair":false,
        "outputs":2,
        "x":1270,
        "y":660,
        "wires":[
            [
                "616445ea.a0d8dc"
            ],
            [
                "925a9ecb.31de7"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"616445ea.a0d8dc",
        "type":"change",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"Closed",
        "rules":[
            {
                "t":"set",
                "p":"payload",
                "pt":"msg",
                "to":"{\"CurrentDoorState\":1,\"TargetDoorState\":1}",
                "tot":"json"
            }
        ],
        "action":"",
        "property":"",
        "from":"",
        "to":"",
        "reg":false,
        "x":1460,
        "y":600,
        "wires":[
            [
                "5aaf7b8d.70aa14"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"925a9ecb.31de7",
        "type":"change",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"Open",
        "rules":[
            {
                "t":"set",
                "p":"payload",
                "pt":"msg",
                "to":"{\"CurrentDoorState\":0,\"TargetDoorState\":0}",
                "tot":"json"
            }
        ],
        "action":"",
        "property":"",
        "from":"",
        "to":"",
        "reg":false,
        "x":1450,
        "y":720,
        "wires":[
            [
                "5aaf7b8d.70aa14"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"b97366ab.e6f5c8",
        "type":"function",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"Flag Triggered (Compare the values.)",
        "func":"var CDS = global.get(\"CDS\");\nvar TDS = global.get(\"TDS\");\n\nif (CDS == TDS) {\n        msg.payload = \"same\";\n    } else {\n        msg.payload = \"different\";\n}",
        "outputs":1,
        "noerr":0,
        "x":970,
        "y":460,
        "wires":[
            [
                "47743f0.13daac",
                "81d95da8.e8a44"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"f7605409.237dc8",
        "type":"function",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"Set Global Variable",
        "func":"global.set(\"CDS\", 1)",
        "outputs":1,
        "noerr":0,
        "x":1170,
        "y":860,
        "wires":[
            [

            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"238c6754.5f47d8",
        "type":"function",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"Set Global Variable",
        "func":"global.set(\"CDS\", 0)",
        "outputs":1,
        "noerr":0,
        "x":1150,
        "y":1100,
        "wires":[
            [

            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"b056b7c4.7ac138",
        "type":"function",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"Set Global Variable",
        "func":"global.set(\"TDS\", 0)",
        "outputs":1,
        "noerr":0,
        "x":2570,
        "y":760,
        "wires":[
            [

            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"c83a643c.349788",
        "type":"function",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"Set Global Variable",
        "func":"global.set(\"TDS\", 1)",
        "outputs":1,
        "noerr":0,
        "x":2570,
        "y":560,
        "wires":[
            [

            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"47743f0.13daac",
        "type":"switch",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"Are they the same?",
        "property":"payload",
        "propertyType":"msg",
        "rules":[
            {
                "t":"eq",
                "v":"same",
                "vt":"str"
            },
            {
                "t":"eq",
                "v":"different",
                "vt":"str"
            }
        ],
        "checkall":"true",
        "repair":false,
        "outputs":2,
        "x":1230,
        "y":460,
        "wires":[
            [
                "81d95da8.e8a44",
                "9d51ba2e.5e2068"
            ],
            [
                "a485cea6.9391e"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"898514ea.ccbd98",
        "type":"file",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"Reset Flag",
        "filename":"/home/carter/garage/vars/changing",
        "appendNewline":false,
        "createDir":false,
        "overwriteFile":"delete",
        "x":1640,
        "y":360,
        "wires":[

        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"81d95da8.e8a44",
        "type":"debug",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"",
        "active":true,
        "tosidebar":true,
        "console":false,
        "tostatus":false,
        "complete":"false",
        "x":1230,
        "y":320,
        "wires":[

        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"1c403c26.e50284",
        "type":"file",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"Flag as Changing State",
        "filename":"/home/carter/garage/vars/changing",
        "appendNewline":false,
        "createDir":false,
        "overwriteFile":"true",
        "x":2590,
        "y":640,
        "wires":[

        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"9d51ba2e.5e2068",
        "type":"function",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"Same",
        "func":"msg.payload.TargetDoorState = global.get(\"CDS\")\nmsg.payload.CurrentDoorState = global.get(\"CDS\")\nreturn msg;\n",
        "outputs":1,
        "noerr":0,
        "x":1410,
        "y":400,
        "wires":[
            [
                "898514ea.ccbd98",
                "5aaf7b8d.70aa14"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"a485cea6.9391e",
        "type":"function",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"Different",
        "func":"msg.payload.CurrentDoorState = global.get(\"CDS\")\nmsg.payload.TargetDoorState = global.get(\"TDS\")\nreturn msg;",
        "outputs":1,
        "noerr":0,
        "x":1420,
        "y":480,
        "wires":[
            [
                "5aaf7b8d.70aa14"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"e80c8bfd.7c1e38",
        "type":"inject",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"Close",
        "topic":"",
        "payload":"{\"CurrentDoorState\":1,\"TargetDoorState\":1}",
        "payloadType":"json",
        "repeat":"",
        "crontab":"",
        "once":false,
        "onceDelay":0.1,
        "x":1510,
        "y":920,
        "wires":[
            [
                "5aaf7b8d.70aa14"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"99f97edb.06267",
        "type":"inject",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"Open",
        "topic":"",
        "payload":"{\"CurrentDoorState\":0,\"TargetDoorState\":0}",
        "payloadType":"json",
        "repeat":"",
        "crontab":"",
        "once":false,
        "onceDelay":0.1,
        "x":1510,
        "y":960,
        "wires":[
            [
                "5aaf7b8d.70aa14"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"5aaf7b8d.70aa14",
        "type":"homekit-service",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "accessory":"84bf4323.627db",
        "name":"Main Garage",
        "serviceName":"GarageDoorOpener",
        "x":1650,
        "y":660,
        "wires":[
            [
                "253a0e02.550b52"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"c3a8e2c.70bb52",
        "type":"comment",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"Get the status every 5 seconds.",
        "info":"",
        "x":290,
        "y":720,
        "wires":[

        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"9f4f1241.e9102",
        "type":"comment",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"Retrieve the flag file and check if its active.",
        "info":"",
        "x":740,
        "y":700,
        "wires":[

        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"f2482231.68842",
        "type":"comment",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"Write the CDS to a file.",
        "info":"",
        "x":840,
        "y":1160,
        "wires":[

        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"e37ab710.a21a88",
        "type":"comment",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"Get the CDS, set it to the TDS, and then feed to HomeKit.",
        "info":"",
        "x":1290,
        "y":780,
        "wires":[

        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"80991a7f.6a9318",
        "type":"comment",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"Compare the global variables. If they are different, the garage is moving, and if they are the same it has stopped.",
        "info":"",
        "x":1180,
        "y":260,
        "wires":[

        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"6f9b114b.d6bfc",
        "type":"comment",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"Delete the flag file, causing the check flag node to throw an error and choose the bottom route.",
        "info":"",
        "x":1860,
        "y":320,
        "wires":[

        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"e64d88ba.07c8d8",
        "type":"comment",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"Send the CDS as the CDS and TDS to HomeKit.",
        "info":"",
        "x":1660,
        "y":400,
        "wires":[

        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"23731949.23c5f6",
        "type":"comment",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"Keep the TDS the same, but report the CDS to HomeKit.",
        "info":"",
        "x":1710,
        "y":480,
        "wires":[

        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"efbfb7a4.54f3b8",
        "type":"comment",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"TDS = TargetDoorState",
        "info":"",
        "x":220,
        "y":240,
        "wires":[

        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"9fb611a6.678ef",
        "type":"comment",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"CDS = CurrentDoorState",
        "info":"",
        "x":230,
        "y":280,
        "wires":[

        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"2562abf.ab67554",
        "type":"comment",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":" 0 = Open",
        "info":"",
        "x":180,
        "y":320,
        "wires":[

        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"a7327588.c00208",
        "type":"comment",
        "z":"b958107d.b6335",
        "name":"1 = Closed",
        "info":"",
        "x":180,
        "y":360,
        "wires":[

        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"84bf4323.627db",
        "type":"homekit-accessory",
        "z":"",
        "accessoryName":"Main",
        "pinCode":"111-11-111",
        "port":"",
        "manufacturer":"Default Manufacturer",
        "model":"Default Model",
        "serialNo":"Default Serial Number",
        "accessoryType":"4"
    }
]
```